# React-Native | panResponder inside ScrollView

Tags: android, react-native, scrollview

I've got horizontal `ScrollView` with some thumbnails. I defined panResponder to my thumbnails in order to drag them on the screen. The problem is that I can't drag them outside the `ScrollView` - the thumbnail become hidden when my finger is exceeds the borders of the `ScrollView`.

There is a way to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: Best bet is to handle panResponder only with a longer press. It's being done over on react-native-sortable-list, which might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Absolute styling if you want to go beyond the parent boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

You can set overflow: 'visible' unfortunately it is working only in iOS because of:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6802

I Had a similar issue:
[How to enable dragging between two react-native-swiper components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45768925/how-to-enable-dragging-between-two-react-native-swiper-components/45795887#45795887)